# Is it possible to fully build an application using a batch file or python (cmake, visual studio command prompt)?

Tags: python, visual-studio, batch-file, cmake

For about a week now I was searching for a problem I see no one has an answer to. There's a mining rig called `xmrig`, its a crypto miner but quite tedious to compile over and over again, the steps to build are that you need to download `cmake`, `visual studio code` and `git`, after this you will have to send commands through the visual studio command prompt [like shown here](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/build/windows) and then you are practically done, I have been stuck on the part of automating command prompt to send those commands all in one command prompt, I have tried both python and batch file but both seem to be getting stuck on the same part, if you know how to do this (preferably python but whatever helps now) please tell me how.

EDIT: The python script looks something like this:

```
import os
os.system(r'cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"" x86')
os.system(r'cmd.exe /k cd xmrig\build')
os.system(r'cmd.exe /k cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2019\x64')
os.system('cmd.exe /k cmake --build . --config Release')
```

And the batch file looks like this:

```
start call cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 
start call cmd.exe /k "cd c:\xmrig\build"
start call cmd.exe /k "cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2019\x64"
start call cmd.exe /k "cmake --build . --config Release"
```

Comment: "Getting stuck on the same part" is not a clear, diagnosable issue... What does your code look like so far? What are the error messages you're receiving?

Comment: No errors, not exact problem in the scripts themselves but the problem how they execute. I want them to do step by step have the commands executed in one command prompt but whenever I execute, they always split into different windows.

Comment: I have added them into the edit

Comment: `cmd.exe /k` means "run this command in a completely separate cmd instance" so the environment never gets set and you never stay in the `C:\xmrig\build` directory.

Comment: Wow, do you know the right way because removing it doesnt change much, now it just stops after first command and closes command prompt.

Comment: Batch file: **line 1.** `@Call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86` **line 2.** `@cd /d "c:\xmrig\build"` **line 3.** `@cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2019\x64`, **line 4.** `@cmake --build . --config Release`